# Message "syntax error near unexpected token `('"

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to execute

```
sudo -su db2inst1 /opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/bin/db2 force application (1995)
```

but I get this error:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

However,

```
sudo -su db2inst1 id
```

gives me correct output. So it must be something about the `()`

If I try

```
sudo -su db2inst1 /opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/bin/db2 force application \(1995\)
```

I get

> /bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `(' \ /bin/bash: -c: line 0:` /opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/bin/db2 force application (1995)'

Running `/opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/bin/db2 force application (1995)` as db2inst1 user gives me the same error, but running

```
/opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/bin/db2 "force application (1995)"
```

works fine

---

The right syntax is

```
sudo -su db2inst1 '/opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/bin/db2 "force application (1995)"'
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

NOTE: While this answer seems to have been correct at the time [sudo was changed later that same year to add extra escaping around characters in the arguments with `-i` and `-s`], it is not correct for modern versions of sudo, which escape all special characters when constructing the command line to be passed to `$SHELL -c`. Always be careful and make sure you know what passing a command to your particular version of sudo will do, and consider carefully whether the `-s` option is really needed for your command and/or, if it would, if you'd be better served with `sudo sh -c`.

---

Since you've got both the shell that you're typing into and the shell that `sudo -s` runs, you need to quote or escape twice. Any of the following three would have worked with this now-ancient version of sudo:

```
sudo -su db2inst1 '/opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/bin/db2 "force application (1995)"'
sudo -su db2inst1 '/opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/bin/db2 force\ application\ \(1995\)'
sudo -su db2inst1 /opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/bin/db2 force\\ application\\ \\\(1995\\\)
```

Out of curiosity, why do you need `-s`? Can't you just do the following?

```
sudo -u db2inst1 /opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/bin/db2 'force application (1995)'
sudo -u db2inst1 /opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/bin/db2 force\ application\ \(1995\)
```

Comment: the first suggestion doesn't work, you need to move the single quote after db2inst1. The next 2 works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
sudo -su db2inst1 /opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/bin/db2 force application \(1995\)
```

Comment: @Radek: Not sure what's happening, but that's definitely **not** a syntax error... :(

Comment: @Radek: Yeah I saw your update, but like I said, that's definitely *not* supposed to be a syntax error; I don't know what's happening. :(

Comment: You might need to do `\\(1995\\)`. One escape for the local shell and one for the remote shell. Or maybe even three parens?